# What does "Context stack underflow" mean in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb, gentoo, underflow, interix

I'm running gdb inside Gentoo inside Interix on Windows XP.  There is a C++ frame in my application that if I enter it, gdb gives the error `Context stack underflow`. Similarly, if I try to set a breakpoint inside that function it also states `Context stack underflow`. I'm using gcc v4.2.4 and gdb 2002-11-11-cvs (which is the only version I know of to work inside Interix Gentoo).

What is this message telling me about my application and how might I resolve it?

Comment: This does not seem to be a gdb error message (at least I could not find it in gdb-7.5.1 or 5.1.1 source).